# How to navigate glibc source?

Tags: c, glibc

I'm trying to learn the glibc source, and I've found *navigation* to be quite formidable.  I'm not referring to the code itself, but simply finding it: it seems to be a maze of macros and wrappers, such that just finding the actual code I want is quite tough.

Not only system dependent things, like `setjmp`, but even portable functions like `fprintf`: in each case, I struggle to find the true definition in C.  It's easy to find the start, but it's usually an empty shell wrapping defines and macros.

This feels like a modern day equivalent of goto statements, with the spaghetti problem all over again.

How can I navigate glibc and find the actual implementation for lib functions?

---

## Update

As an example, try looking up the definition of `hidden_def` in glibc.  It's a macro taking you to `hidden_def1`, which is a macro taking you to `hidden_def2`, which is a macro taking you to `hidden_asm`, which is a macro taking you to `hidden_asm1`, at which point...

Moreover, each of these macros is defined in several different files, with other `#define`s controlling which definition is actually invoked.

This is not unusual: it seems to be de rigeur throughout the source code.  How does anyone follow it? How do the GNU developers follow it?

Comment: You're just gonna have to get used to it.

Comment: Are you studying the source because you want to become a contributor?  Or do you have a specific question about how something within is implemented?  Because at the moment, I can't think of any other good reasons for studying that particular source.

Comment: Yes, it is impressive. The complexity is caused by the need to be platform independent. (it is!) Compare this to Microsoft who struggled a few years to become 64bit ready. (and: Itanium ...)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I navigate glibc and find the actual implementation for lib functions?

Type the function in the search bar at https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc or at https://github.com/bminor/glibc . Navigate the results manually until you find the definition.

If you want to index the project locally, use cscope, ctags, GLOBAL tags or clangd to index the project and then use that tools specific interface to search for the definition.

> As an example, try looking up the definition of hidden_def in glibc

Type `hidden_def glibc` into google. My first hit is woboq.org https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/include/libc-symbols.h.html#550 .

I use firefox. I type `ctrl+f` and type `hidden_def`. Type Enter until I find `# define hidden_def` at https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/include/libc-symbols.h.html#550 .

Then select `__hidden_ver1` and type `ctrl+c` `ctrl+f` and `ctrl+v` and search for it. In the web browser. I type enter until I find https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/include/libc-symbols.h.html#540 . `__hidden_ver2` is just below on line 542.

For most cases all you need is a browser, google, coboq.org and github.org.

> It's a macro taking you to hidden_def1

There are no such macros as you mentioned, at least at the version hosted at woboq.org.

> How does anyone follow it?

While [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) is a powerful help, each project is unique and requires different settings, that take time to figure out. Mostly browsing the source code is `grep` (or faster alternatives, like `ag`, very useful for big projects like glibc) and going through the result list.

> Not only system dependent things, like setjmp

Developers are (shoudl be :) sane people - in most cases a function named `setjmp` will be in a file named `setjmp.c`. or `setjmp.S`. Or in the same directory as `setjmp.h`. Or inside directory named `stdlib` or `setjmp`.

Type `setjmp` in github search bar. https://github.com/bminor/glibc/search?q=setjmp You see there are multiple definitions for each architecture `powerpc` `s390` etc. But files are all named `setjmp`. Go back. Type "Go to file" on https://github.com/bminor/glibc . Search for a file named `x86/setjmp`. There are 3 implementations, the most standard one seems to be https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/x86_64/setjmp.S .

> even portable functions like fprintf

As above, saerch for file named fprintf . You quickly find https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/fprintf.c .